# Content rating level and Ads

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads

I know it's not a pure dev question, but I think Android developers may encounter this issue:

I have an application with "Everyone" content rating level.

Is adding Admob ads to it should change the level to "Low Maturity"?

I got an email from Google Play Team that they changed the app content rating from "Everyone" to "Low Maturity"

And it's the only reason I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the ads you show, if you haven't set any filters to your ads and show everything "Low Maturity" is still good. There are also categories for dating etc., that's nothing for "Everyone" (which includes kids).

Comment: Just to make sure, you say that if I didn't set any filter to my ads, I can't use "Everyone"? And is it your common sense, or you have a source?

Comment: Check out https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en "These guidelines apply to all content in your app, including user generated content, in-app products, and advertisements."

Comment: but i m not use ads in my app then how to change everyone to low maturity...but my app related to jokes